# How can I unescape special characters in HTML meta tags?

Tags: html

In the below meta tag, I have a string `You & Me` in content attribute.

```
<meta name="description" content="You & Me">
```

When I check the snippet in view page source in Chrome, it shows up like the below

```
<meta name="description" content="You &amp; Me">
```

How can I unescape the string so that `&` shows up correctly?
FYI, I'm using Django as backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XHTML, `&` is a reserved character and must be encoded as `&amp;`.  What Chrome is showing you is correct.  Chrome is interpreting your invalid/broken XHTML and showing you the corrected version.  Therefore, there's nothing to correct except your original HTML to make it look like Chrome has interpreted it anyway.